# Duplicate Leads from License Management App

Tags: leads, appexchange, duplicate-management

We have an App on the AppExchange and for some reason, we get Leads with the same email address and name as duplicate with that Lead Source. Does anybody know why this is, and/or how to prevent this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your org where LMA in installed configure salesforce standard [Duplicate Management Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_standard_lead_rule.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

It is an OOB configuration which is simple to set up and maintain and provide matching rules on email Id .

The reason for this happening might be same user trying to install your app in multiple instances using the same credentials .

Comment: While Duplicate Management Rules may work to solve the problem, it isn't the answer to the question. I don't believe that a customer is installing our app in 5-6 instances. 1-3, I may believe, but that is too much.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the examples of the Lead Sources, as they may have different codes on them.

Depending on your package set-up, the process can create multiple Leads during the process, such as:

- Watching the demo
- Requesting a Test Drive
- Starting the installation
- Completing the installation

To check the settings, you'd need to log into the appexchange account which include this package.

Further information: [AppExchange - What do the lead source codes from my listing mean?](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/resource/1352496302000/help/index_Left.htm#CSHID=appexchange_leads_how_to_get.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fappexchange_leads_how_to_get.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)